# Typescript property reference inside a property

Tags: javascript, typescript, properties

I have a property declared below:

```
export const properties = {
  username: 'admin',
  password: 'pass',
  environment: 'test1',
  // Trying to construct the url so it becomes http://test1.com
  url: 'http://'  + environment + '.com',

};
```

I would like to reuse `environment` inside the url value. However it can't seem the find it. I have tried the following and had no luck:

```
url: 'http://'  + environment + '.com',
url: 'http://'  + this.environment + '.com',
url: 'http://'  + properties.environment + '.com',
```

Does anyone have any idea on how it can be done? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of the following:

```js
const properties = {
  username: 'admin',
  password: 'pass',
  environment: 'test1',
  // Trying to construct the url so it becomes http://test1.com
  get url() {
    return 'http://' + this.environment + '.com';
  },
};
```

(The above makes use of getter function, which has a different behaviors than a normal property, but it behaves very similarly in most cases)

or

```js
const environment = 'test1';

const properties = {
  username: 'admin',
  password: 'pass',
  environment,
  // Trying to construct the url so it becomes http://test1.com
  url: 'http://'  + environment + '.com',
};
```